# IUPAC salt definition makes bases be classified as salts?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

The IUPAC salt definition is: "A chemical compound consisting of an assembly of cations and anions" (Compendium of Chemical Terminology Gold Book, Version 2.2.3, 2014)

So it means that a base like NaOH, that's also an ionic crystal, is a salt? I'm quite certain it's not but it seems the definition says so.

Then, a if a base is not a salt, what would be a better definition for salt?

Comment: There is no good definition of salt, or even "ionic" compound.

Comment: $\ce{NaH2PO4}$ acts as an acid when dissolved in pure water, yet it is a salt, no?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/117914/is-an-acid-a-salt-or-not https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/96090/what-is-the-difference-between-an-ionic-compound-and-a-salt

Comment: NaOH can be formally considered as a salt of the very weak acid H2O, making it a very strong conjugate base of the H2O acid.